# Function seteuid() called from set-root-id program works but shows error msg

Tags: c, setuid

I compiled this sample set-root-id program:

```
  #define _GNU_SOURCE

  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <errno.h>


  void print_ids()
     {
     uid_t ruid, euid, suid, rgid, egid, sgid;

     getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
     printf("\nruid=%d, euid=%d, suid=%d\n", ruid, euid, suid);

     getresgid(&rgid, &egid, &sgid);
     printf("rgid=%d, egid=%d, sgid=%d\n\n", rgid, egid, sgid);
     }


  void main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
     print_ids();
     seteuid(1000); printf("seteuid(1000): %s\n", strerror(errno));
     print_ids();
     seteuid(1001); printf("seteuid(1001): %s\n", strerror(errno));
     print_ids();
     seteuid(0);    printf("seteuid(0): %s\n",    strerror(errno));   
     print_ids();
     }
```

Call to seteuid(0) works, but dislays an error message: "Operation not permitted":

```
$ gcc -Wall ./p3.c -o p3
./p3.c:32: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
$ su -c "chown root:root ./p3 ; chmod 4755 ./p3"
Password: ****
$ ls -l ./p3
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7697  2 gen 19.21 ./p3
$ ./p3

ruid=1000, euid=0, suid=0
rgid=1000, egid=1000, sgid=1000

seteuid(1000): Success

ruid=1000, euid=1000, suid=0
rgid=1000, egid=1000, sgid=1000

seteuid(1001): Operation not permitted

ruid=1000, euid=1000, suid=0
rgid=1000, egid=1000, sgid=1000

seteuid(0): Operation not permitted

ruid=1000, euid=0, suid=0
rgid=1000, egid=1000, sgid=1000

$
```

Why seteuid(0) works but displays the error message?
I noticed that omitting call to seteuid(1001) or call to seteuid(1000) no error messages appear.

Thank you

(I work on Debian 6, gcc version 4.4.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old `EPERM` is still in `errno` from the previous call. Successful system calls do not set `errno` to 0; you have to do that yourself.

Usually, you don't need to set `errno` to 0. You check the return value of the system call, and then if that indicates failure, you check `errno` for more details. errno doesn't tell you *that* something failed - it tells you *how* something failed.

There's an exception to this general rule for functions with no distinct error indicator in their return value, like `strtoul`, but `seteuid` isn't one of those. It has a clean return value. If it returns 0, you shouldn't print an error message at all.

And relying on `strerror(0)` to produce a "success message" isn't clean either - in current glibc it says `"Success"` but I can still remember when `strerror(0)` was `"Unknown error 0"`. Maybe somewhere it still is.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking on somewhat else.  'man seteuid' says: "On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately." exactly as you said.